# How to solve this Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, maple, linear-pde

I am struggeling with the following PDE:

$u_t+a(x,y)u_{xx}+b(x,y)u_{xy}+c(x,y)u_{yy}+d(x,y)u_{x}+e(x,y)u_{y}+f(x,y)u=0$
$u(T,x,y)=1,$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are polynomials and the domain is the set $\{(t,x,y):t\in[0,T],x+y=1,x\geq0,y\geq0\}$.

I showed, however, that there exists a unique solution and I would like to have this solution explicitly, either via Maple/Matlab or *by hand*. My problem hereby is that this PDE is not in the right form for Matlab, Maple is not able to solve it ([here my post in mapleprime](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/225223-Maple-Doesnt-Solve-My-PDE-With-Pdsolve-Why?reply=reply)) and I don't know how to handle this by hand.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,

utcyp